# Ignoring the user result input when updating data goes wrong

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working on an :
`edit.blade.php`

where users can edit data and the update method of Controller goes here:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $discountCode = DiscountCode::find($id);

        $request->validate([
            'code' => 'unique:discount_codes,code'.$discountCode->id,
            'started_at' => 'required_if:timespan,TRUE',
            'ended_at' => 'required_if:timespan,TRUE',
        ],
  
        ...
    }
```

So as you can see the `code` must be uique in `discount_codes` table.

So I tried adding :

`$discountCode->id`

in order to ignore unique validation rule for the current data but it does not work out and returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'code15' in 

'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 

`discount_codes` where `code15` = GIGvJjp4PM)
```

**15** is my data row id.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: because you concatenated `code'.$discountCode->id,`. so it results in `"code15"`, use Rule class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Rule::class` to create the rule and ignore specific id

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

//...

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $discountCode = DiscountCode::findOrFail($id);

    $request->validate([
        'code' => [Rule::unique('discount_codes')->ignore($id)],
        'started_at' => 'required_if:timespan,TRUE',
        'ended_at' => 'required_if:timespan,TRUE',
    ],

    ...
}
```